# Split Grammar and Grammar Attributes (Procedural Generation of Buildings)

Tags: grammar, procedural-generation

I am trying to implement algorithm for procedural generation of buildings for my thesis. I've been reading a lot about shape/split grammars. Here's the [link](http://peterwonka.net/Publications/pdfs/2006.SG.Mueller.ProceduralModelingOfBuildings.final.pdf) to the most popular paper covering that topic.
I managed to implement very basic grammar without attributes and guard conditions. It can generate primitives, and do geometric transformations. I'm using flex and bison to parse shape grammar files, and generate objects (Symbols, Rules etc.) that representat given grammar in object oriented manner that could later be called to generate geometry.
But now I'm stuck with the attribute part. For example:

```
fac(h) : h > 9; floor(h/3) floor(h/3) floor(h/3)
```

I am clueless how to represent grammar to contains informations about attributes, how to pass values to the symbols on the left and how to evaluate condition.
Can anyone help me with this, please? I'm using C++.

Note: I have some knowledge about grammars and parsers, and I know how to implement top-down parser with attributes using recursive descent but that approach is useless here. I can't generate source code for functions because interpretation of grammar files will be done in the same runtime as the application. Even if I could, this is not parser but generator of sentences and there are lot more problems like condition evaluation and production selection.